# Is there a way to programmatically decline a turn-based match in GameKit?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

In a `GKTurnBasedMatch`, each `GKTurnBasedParticipant` has a `status` property.  I would like to set this property to `GKTurnBasedParticipantStatusDeclined`; however, it is read-only.  How can I programmatically do this?

To my knowledge, it can only be done from the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` or by clearing an Invite notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you have to use `-[GKTurnBasedMatch (void)participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:(GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome)matchOutcome nextParticipant:(GKTurnBasedParticipant *)nextPlayer matchData:(NSData *)matchData completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler]` to do so

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 6.0 we have new method of GKTurnBasedMatch

```
- (void)declineInviteWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```